# No matching Shape found. Slick does not know how to map the given types

Tags: scala, playframework, slick

My case class

```
case class Entry(id: Int, title: String, content: String,
                                 publishedDate: Date, views: Int)
```

The Schena

```
class Entries(tag: Tag) extends Table[Entry](tag, "ENTRIES") {
        def id = column[Int]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
        def title = column[String]("title")
        def content = column[String]("content")
        def publishedDate = column[Date]("published_date")
        def views = column[Int]("views")

        override def * = (id, title, content, publishedDate, views) <> (Entry.tupled, Entry.unapply)
    }

val entries = TableQuery[Entries]
```

My query:

```
def byId(id: Rep[Int]) = for (entry <- entries if entry.id === id) yield entry.first
val entryById = Compiled(byId _)
def get(id: Int): Option[Entry] = db.Schema.entryById(id).result.run(DB)
```

When I run I got this error: No matching Shape found. Slick does not know 
how to map the given types.

Play: 2.4
Scala: 2.11.6
Slick: 3.1.1

EDIT: I've also got "value first is not a member of db.Schema.Entries" and a similiar error for "result"

Answer (score 2):

Methods `first` and `fistOption` are removed in slick 3.0.0. Use `head` or `headOption`.

Answer (score 1):

You may be using `java.util.Date`. I think `java.sql.Date` and `java.sql.Timestamp` are supported out of the box, but not `java.util.Date`.

You easily fix this by switching to `java.sql.Date` or you could have created a [MappedColumnType](http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.2.0/userdefined.html#using-custom-scalar-types-in-queries) to tell slick how to use it.

```
implicit val javaUtilDateColumnType = MappedColumnType.base[java.util.Date, java.sql.Date](
  ud => new java.sql.Date(ud.getTime), sd => new java.util.Date(sd.getTime)
)
```